# Android apps will run on API 25 only

Tags: android, android-studio

This is very strange now. No matter what project it is, my android app wont run on any other roms but API 25 based only.The default `hello world` app even wont run on any other API. 
**Basically the apk installation fails on every other rom other than the ones that are nouugat based.**

My `minsdkversion` is 21 though

Here is the build.gradle(Module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.rishav.basictest"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
}
```

Build.gradle(Project):-

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha4'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: What's the failure reason?

Comment: What happens when you run an app on an API 21 device?

Comment: @GabeSechan Error shows in android studio saying "Apk couldnt install -0"

Comment: @Code-Apprentice The same thing. It doesnt install at all.

Comment: Hi I am kind of new to android development and I am facing the same issue. Even when I make a project with Jellybean selected it wont install on other API levels but nougat only. Using sdk 26.0.0 maybe has something to do with this. It **probably** started for me when I started using `26.0.0`

Comment: @Rishav When in doubt, assume that this is one of AS alpha/beta's bugs that's worth reporting to the Android team ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem..

In Android Studio 2.3 and higher, There is Instant Run which may affect your code.

Disable **Instant Run**

```
File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run
```

In my case it was working perfect,i hope may this will help you.

Comment: Ill try disabling instant run and report back. But shouldn't it be irrelevant as the issue still persists even after i export my app. :(   


N btw i am using Android Studio 3.0 canary 4